# How to don't start with pinned page?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I pinned a page in Google Chrome. Every time I start Chrome, the pinned page is there and it's loading. However, I don't want that any more so I unpinned the page, but Chrome still starts with the pinned page. (It's probably a bug, I don't know.)
So the question is, can I do anything with the Chrome settings (even if only in some setting files with a text editor) to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's really a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44645&q=unpin&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) after all. In the [comment of the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44645&q=unpin&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS#c1) they suggest to clear the browsing data as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Chrome set to reload pages from last session or open specific sites on startup? To check, go to Preferences -> Basics (at least on Mac). Then look at the *On Startup* settings.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's set to open the new tab page.